# software center doesn't load

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python, software-center

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. when I go to Ubuntu Software Center it is **automatically closed after 1 second**.

```
2017-04-02 14:44:06,970 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2017-04-02 14:44:07,356 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2017-04-02 14:44:07,358 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2017-04-02 14:44:07,391 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2017-04-02 14:44:07,796 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2017-04-02 14:44:07,796 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
    self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
    0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 68 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 152, in open
    self._depcache = apt_pkg.DepCache(self._cache)
SystemError: E:The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 193, in init_view
    SoftwarePane.init_view(self)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/softwarepane.py", line 138, in init_view
    self.icons, self.show_ratings)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appview.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.helper = AppPropertiesHelper(db, cache, icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/models/appstore2.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.all_categories = cat_parser.parse_applications_menu()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 277, in parse_applications_menu
    category = self._parse_menu_tag(child)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 473, in _parse_menu_tag
    query = self._parse_include_tag(element)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 431, in _parse_include_tag
    xapian.Query.OP_AND)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 368, in _parse_and_or_not_tag
    operator_elem, xapian.Query(), xapian.Query.OP_OR)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 414, in _parse_and_or_not_tag
    q = self.db.xapian_parser.parse_query(s,
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 185, in xapian_parser
    xapian_parser = self._get_new_xapian_parser()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 211, in _get_new_xapian_parser
    xapian_parser.set_database(self.xapiandb)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 177, in xapiandb
    self._db_per_thread[thread_name] = self._get_new_xapiandb()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/database.py", line 190, in _get_new_xapiandb
    xapiandb = xapian.Database(self._db_pathname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xapian/__init__.py", line 3667, in __init__
    _xapian.Database_swiginit(self,_xapian.new_Database(*args))
xapian.DatabaseOpeningError: Couldn't stat '/var/cache/software-center/xapian' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Before anything else make sure it's fully updated: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. If any error messages please edit the question and post the full error messages.

Comment: I tried the above code. No error messages. It goes as usual, downloading packages from the sources